# Why invoke Elixir Kernel.apply/2 instead of calling the anonymous function?

Tags: elixir

Why use `apply/2` when we can call the anonymous function?

It's not the same?

```
iex(40)> f = fn x -> x + 1 end
#Function<7.126501267/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(41)> apply(f, [1])
2
iex(42)> f.(1)
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the typical use case for [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#apply/3) would be a dynamic invocation when `{m, f, a}` are not static, [`Kernel.apply/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#apply/2) [most likely] exists to simplify piping the function to its application.

```rb
(&Integer.digits/1) # or any other anonymous function
|> apply([42])      # easy piping to application
|> Enum.join()      # more piping
#⇒ "42"
```